# embed iframe from videos.sh in my nuxt website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, nuxt.js

I want to embed video within an iframe from videos.sh in my website [www.footfoot.co](http://www.footfoot.co) but i can't manage to do it.

here is the result :
https://www.footfoot.co/news/babble/5ff6e941542cb400641bf778

If i try with an iframe from an other source it works :
https://www.footfoot.co/teams/spurs/babble/5ff4ed3f3f497f00389356ea

I'm looking for help to understand where does the problem come from please.

It only happens with chrome, with firefox it works for my site.
The same video from videos.sh plays on other website with chrome.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You see the dark gray text that says _Embeds disabled_?

Comment: yes Embeds disabled5

Comment: That is my hint. You are trying to embed a video, but video embeds are disabled by the video provider

Comment: no i don't think so it plays on firefox, only problems with chrome. Other site embed the same video and it works on chrome.

Comment: That's one information that is missing in your OP. Please add it above

Comment: thanks i make the change